# Divergent RAM consumption, which program to trust? | htop | free -m | top | glances | CPU-X

Tags: command-line, ram, monitoring

I'm studying about processes and RAM consumption and I noticed differences in the RAM memory consumption information when using different programs. I'm using Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy) fully updated as of today's date. The programs show the information below.

**Glances:** 4.70 GB used

**HTOP:** 4.35 GB used

**Free -m / top:** 3.51 GB used (3604 MB, Considering conversion by 1024)

**CPU-X:** 3.52 GB used (I consider the result equal to free -m and top due to rounding in the conversion)

[image]

*The question is, are Glances and HTOP totally unrealistic and would the top and free -m commands be trusted to get this information?*
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> noticed differences in the RAM memory consumption information when using different programs"

In principle both are correct. It is a design difference or a difference in philosophy: htop (and I assume glances) counts cached as used, free does not.

See `/proc/meminfo` It will list every element (sofware will get its info from there):

```
$ more /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       16066704 kB
MemFree:          932060 kB
MemAvailable:   11062388 kB
Buffers:          372532 kB
Cached:         10243404 kB
SwapCached:          288 kB
Active:          7641332 kB
Inactive:        6286892 kB
Active(anon):      58624 kB
Inactive(anon):  3946760 kB
Active(file):    7582708 kB
Inactive(file):  2340132 kB
Unevictable:      307148 kB
Mlocked:             160 kB
SwapTotal:       1897016 kB
SwapFree:        1871928 kB
```

Comment: But if we look at the free -m information, in my case 13 GB is being used for cache. If the glances and the HTOP added the used RAM with the total cache, the result would be almost 17 GB.

Comment: The information of cat /proc/meminfo shows that 12GB is cached. Buffers: 558848 kB -Cached: 12751708 kB
In this case the sum of used RAM + cache would result in approximately 16 GB